# UIGestureRecognizerState.Ended is not called in some cases

Tags: ios, swift, uigesturerecognizer, uipangesturerecognizer

When I drag the view and let it go in a new location .Ended is called everytime.

When I drag the view for a while and let it go in the same location it started, nothing is called, I expect .Ended or default to be called but doesn't happen.

Why does this happen? How can I learn when the user let go of the view consistently?

```
var gestureRecognizer = UIPanGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: Selector("dragged:"))
gestureRecognizer.delegate = self
view.addGestureRecognizer(gestureRecognizer)

func dragged(gesture: UIPanGestureRecognizer) {
    switch gesture.state {
    case UIGestureRecognizerState.Began:
        print("calls this everytime touch began")
    case UIGestureRecognizerState.Ended:
        print("doesn't call this everytime")
    default: 
        print("never calls this")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You should almost always use UIGestureRecognizerState.Ended || UIGestureRecognizerState.Cancelled as one of the two will definitely be called at the end of a gesture. This way you can also handle cases where the user has dragged past the screen.

Comment: I'm running into a similar issue where Changed is called, but Cancelled or Ended is not getting called

Comment: same thing here. do u find any solution ?\

Comment: same here, has anybody found a solution for this?

Comment: Having both a pan gesture and tap gesture can cause issues.  When panning, the tap gesture is sometimes called just before the pan gesture ends.  Depending on your code, this may cause a problem.  To prevent the tap gesture from being called during panning use `tap.require(toFail: pan)` (**use your recognizer names**).

Answer (score 1):

This happened to me when I had a case for `.recognized` in my switch statement (don't do this).

Comment: Its nice that it worked, but I still do not get why. because .ended is a raw value 3

Answer (score 0):

In my case this happened only when I used two-finger pinch or rotate gestures in the Simulator, using the *option* key on the keyboard.

Usually pressing the *option* key once more after the gesture has ended (without moving the mouse) seems to resolve the issue and the `.ended` state is reached.

I did not encounter this problem on an actual device.